# NGINX: What is wrong with my nginx configuration

Tags: angular, rest, spring-mvc, nginx

I have an angular app being served by nginx , this angular app talks to a rest backend on the same server.

I have following two server configuration in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/

"default" and "app" 
Angular app is being served correctly by default server listening on 80 .

```
  server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
    }
```

}

Then in my "app" server block which should redirect requests for rest backend ,

```
server{
    listen [::]:80 ;

    server_name xxx.com;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

But when my angular app hits a POST API end points it gets a 405(method not allowed), which is happening because it directly hits the nginx server not even going to rest endpoint(on 8082), otherwise an OPTIONS would be sent first , but I see only one request being made and that of POST directly, which means it's not even redirecting to other port otherwise CORS settings would be invoked in my REST backend.
I don't know what i did wrong, the same app works perfectly fine locally.
I have double checked the symlinks in sites-enabled folder, they are absolute paths.

EDIT:
MY request headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

My Os 
Ubuntu: 16.04 , 
nginx :1.10.3 .

Comment: try to run nginx -t and post the output.

Comment: @advay.umare
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I think in your app server block you need to add 8082 in place of 
listen [::]:80;

Comment: no that is not correct, the whole idea of having proxy_pass is that to listen on 80 and pass it to 8082, thats how we use any reverse proxy

Comment: yes but on 80 you have angular app running and that's causing request to redirect to angular app where it's not getting the rest endpoints. Which Server are you using in backend.

Comment: "default" 80 is just serving the static contents like index.html, which is the starting page of  any angular app. after that angular app runs in client side. Not sure what you mean by angular running on 80, then when the angular app hits xxx.com  at 80, it should go to 127.0.0.1:8082, which is not happening, I am using embedded tomcat spring boot for rest backend

Comment: Are you sure the API requests are made using the `xxx.com` name in the Host header? Else you would always call the default virtualhost.

Comment: @regilero , I have verified the host header, it does contain the xxx.com domain, (but of course no port number), so it should go to 80 and then to 8082

Comment: Did you enable debugging on nginx and check nginx log files?

Answer (score 1):

try merging both server blocks:

```
 server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and access all the rest apis by appending '/api/' in the url.

May be its CORS issue, Add this in your location block:

```
  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
  }
```

Comment: @TruckDriver Its may be CORS issue. I have made edit to my answer. Try That.